# Adding full directory via diff & patch

Tags: linux, directory, diff, patch

Is it possible to add a full directory via diff and patch?

It seems as very convenient way to add additional modules on top of standard code-base.

I googled for some solutions, but they generally work on file level, not on directory level.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you just tried to "create" a file in a subfolder with a patch?

Comment: That is working, but I needed to create a full directory structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering myself:

diff -urPp old_dir/ new_dir/ > new_module.patch

Seems to do the trick.

Comment: Thanks! Just what I wanted. In case it helps someone else, use `--exclude=PATTERN` to exclude things like CVS directories, and you can apply this patch to an entire directory with `patch -p1 <new_module.patch`.

Answer (score 2):

Two quick suggestions--these should help

1. You need the flag `-r | --recursive`
2. You probably also need `--unidirectional-new-file` or `-N | --new-file`.

as I have done what you have in mind here.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work as well, though -P gives a bit more control to prevent accidental mistakes.

Comment: Yes, I tried to help quickly. I have sample invocations at home that are probably closer to what you ended up with.   Excluding CVS / SVN is also useful.

Answer (score 0):

Below steps will work

1. Taking patch between the old source code and new source code (new files + new directories)
   diff -urPp old_src new_src > new.patch
2. create a temp directory
   mkdir temp
3. copy the original old source code directory to temp directory
   cp -r old_src temp
4. copy the patch file to temp directory created
   cp new.patch temp
5. change directory
   cd temp
6. apply patch
   patch -p0 < new.patch

Now all the patches would be applied with file changes + new files + directory addition in the temp directory